# How to hide the vertical line on searchview on hint and show it on query?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-custom-view, searchview

I want to hide the vertical bar on searchview edittext if the hint appears and the user didn't write any query and if he tried to make a query it will be show after the word written and if he removes the query and the hint get back the vertical bar hide again.

The vertical bar I mean appears in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sHQf.jpg) with gray color in the start of the searchview edittext also I want it appears like [this image](https://static.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/searchview-on-toolbar3.png) on query written

I have tried this in the custom style for searchview but it didn't hide the cursor

```
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can hide the cursor by following

```
android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

Although this might also remove the bottom horizontal bar, I guess you can make a work around about it to set a query listener and check if the text of SearchView is empty then set background as transparent else default.

Comment: I used a custom background for android:queryBackground

Comment: Custom background as in a drawable? If so you can assign it via `android:background ` property, please clarify a bit.